# How to add multiple files in xml file in TestNG

Tags: java, selenium, testng

While creating xml file to run all java files, it is not showing all java file,

[image]

if adding file name manually then also it is not running all the java file

```
<!DOCTYPE suite SYSTEM "http://testng.org/testng-1.0.dtd">
<suite name="Suite">
  <test thread-count="5" name="Test">
    <classes>
      <class name="Entry.StatusHistory"/>
      <class name="Entry.Dashboard"/>
    </classes>
  </test> <!-- Test -->
</suite> <!-- Suite -->
```

It is only running Entry.StatusHistory this file.
How to solve this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please make sure that you've used **testNG** annotations in **Dashboard** class. As this happens when you have no test cases in your class(**@test**). So, **testNG.xml** will not run that class.

Comment: Used (@Test) in both files then also it is not running.
Because I placed (@Test) on different position in both files.
Ok Thank You got my mistake.

Comment: Thanks for marking this as answer, really appreciated.